# Looping to create a custom String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am looping to write data to an array of Strings. But what I want is that I create another loop where I will loop through the data of `values` as much as `amount`, but I would like to have some guidance on how to do so.

```
String[] s = new String[20];
String[] values = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
final int amount = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s[i] = String.format("%s%04d", values[0], i); //TODO create another loop?
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

The preferred output should be:

```
A0000, A0001, B0002, B0003, C0004, ...
```

The actual output is:

```
A0000, A0001, A0002, A0003, A0004, ...
```

Comment: Please specify the the actual output, show the complete output you want.

Comment: @rakeb.void I have edited the original post.

Comment: Your "preferred" and "actual" outputs totally do not agree.  Please reconcile this.

Comment: Still not clear, from where the `I` came into output `IA20000`? Why you used `values[0]` in `String.format`? What will be the purpose of `"B", "C", "D"` in `values`?

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));` would get you the desired output to some degree, but the code you've shared doesn't show what you put in the `classes` variable that you're using as output provider...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Problem : your looping is wrong.

try this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

          int k=0;
          String[] s = new String[20];
            String[] values = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
            final int amount = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){

                 for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++){ //data of values as much as amount
                  s[k++] = String.format("%s%04d", values[i], k); 
                 }
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(s,k)));
     }
```

output:

```
[A0001, A0002, B0003, B0004, C0005, C0006, D0007, D0008]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 2 loops one to loop through the actual `values` array then another one is the `amount` (number of times).

Try this

```
    List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] values = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
    final int amount = 2;
    int incrementVariable = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< amount; j++){
            a.add(String.format("%s%04d", values[i], incrementVariable)); 
            incrementVariable +=1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Output:

```
[A0000, A0001, B0002, B0003, C0004, C0005, D0006, D0007]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like while loops better :)

```
String[] s = new String[10];
String[] values = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
final int amount = 2;

for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    int buffer = 0;
    while(buffer <= amount) {
        int index = i * amount + buffer;
        s[index] = values[i] + String.format("%04d", index);
        buffer++;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
```

> [A0000, A0001, B0002, B0003, C0004, C0005, D0006, D0007, D0008, null]